# Variable will not stay set after being modified inside of a PIPE while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, variable, subshell

I was writing a script, and ran into a problem where my variable will not stay set when I modify it from inside of a `| while` loop.  To illustrate, I wrote this example:

```
#!/bin/bash

thevar="Foo"

grep "somestring" testfile.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do
    thevar+=" bar"
    echo "The var is now: $thevar"
done

echo+="But as soon as we get out of the while,the var goes back to $thevar"
```

Which outputs:

```
The var is now: Foo bar
But as soon as we get out of the while,the var goes back to Foo
```

Why is this happening, and what can I do to keep my variable?

Comment: That isn't how you echo a full array.  Use: `echo "${thevar[@]}"`.  Also that isn't how you add an element to an array.  Use: `thevar+=('bar')`.

Comment: @Jesse_b I'm not messing with arrays, just appending to a variable...

Comment: Try like this then:  `thevar="$thevar bar"`

Comment: @Jesse_b, That doesn't make a difference.  The appending is working just fine.  Take a closer look at the output.

Comment: @Kusalananda  Should I delete this?  The other question doesn't address how to work around it...

Comment: @Questionmark That is totally up to you.